# Looking for a server 2003 to 2012 upgrade path

Tags: windows-server-2003

Looking for a complete upgrade path from a 2003 R2 domain to 2012. Would like to transfer fsmo roles and also upgrade sql from 2005 to 2010 or later and exhange 2003 to 2010. Ive been looking on here and other places but haven't been able to find anything. Would it be better to transfer to 2008 and then move to 2012 or just start fresh in 2012. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Two things that will affect your plan. First, you cannot do an in-place upgrade of Exchange Server 2003 and later. Transitioning the organisation requires installing new (64-bit) Exchange 2010 servers and transferring mailboxes, public folders, address list generation, etc. Second, you cannot do an inplace upgrade from 32-bit Windows (which your Server 2003 machines probably are) to 64-bit Windows. Given this, it sounds like you should be looking at not doing any in-place upgrades but installing new Windows Server 2012 servers and moving data across.

Comment: +1 for doing it over and starting fresh.  In my experience, older domains tend to get gummed up over time due to various reasons.  If you installation is large, script the account creation, file migtration, security ACLs and then migrate mail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually doing this exact same thing right now.

We are currently running SBS 2003, Exchange 2003 and MSSQL 2000.

I looked at upgrading in-place but in all honesty, it would be very messy to say the least. So over the past couple of months I've been rebuilding everything from scratch. New Windows 2012 servers, Exchange 2010 and MSSQL 2012 - plus any old 3rd party software I'm upgrading as well as I go along.

It's all being done in VM's on its own little network/IP range so it doesn't interfere with current network. I can have both the old and new VM's side by side on my two screens and use the old one as a reference to setup the new. Fairly straight forward but time consuming.

I've had to recreate each of the user accounts, set up group polices again, migrate MSSQL data, and so on. It's almost completely setup and ready to start migrating users across. This will probably happen in the next month or two.

If you're coming from MSSQL 2005 you can backup your databases and restore then directly into 2012. The only issue I had here was having to delete each of the database security accounts and recreate them again. I'm not sure but without doing this none of our in-house app would connect to the databases.

The main reason I chose this path (recreating everything from scratch) was because our current setup is not in the best shape. It's been upgraded from NT, to 2000, undergone to physical machine migrations plus a migration into a VM. So there is a lot of garbage following it around.

I never created it to begin with and when I took it over, there was no real documentation about it. So I decided to recreate everything from scratch, documenting everything I've done and why and at least now I know everything is setup clean, correctly and in perfect running order.

Depending on the size of your network, I'd recommend this path. It may take a little longer to setup but the end result, in my opinion, will be much better. It's not hard to recreate user accounts, migrate Exchange mailboxes, SQL data and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. This kinda got put on hold for a bit cause we had to put out our phone system just gave out so had to rebuild and other IT fires. But starting to look at this again. Looks like Im going to starting from scratch. Liking the VM idea. Will probably try that.